# Sum of sequence of Vectors in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a sequence of Vectors of doubles: `val vectors = Seq[Vector[Double]]`

I'd like to sum all the vectors in the sequence, i.e. `val total = vectors.sum`

For example, if I have a sequence with two vectors `[1,2]` and `[3,4]`, then the result should be `[4,6]`

However, the `sum` method of the `Vector` type requires an implicit `Numeric`.

What I have now is:

```
val total = vectors.reduce( (one,two) => one.zip(two).map(tuple => tuple._1 + tuple._2) )
```

I'm new to Scala, but I find this confusing and I assume that it's probably inefficient.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you want a `Seq[Vector[Double]]` or a `Seq[(Double, Double)]`?

Comment: I want just a Vector[Double]. If i have a Seq with two vectors [1,2] and [3,4] then I want [4,6] as the result

Comment: What if there is a `Vector(1, 2, 3)`? Are you sure `Vector` is the data type you want, and not `Tuple2`? They are not the same thing.

Comment: That's a good question in general. In my case, the library that gives me the sequence of vectors guarantees that they're all the same length. Should I convert the Sequence to an Array?

Comment: @BryanGlazer Use a Tuple to guarantee length.

Comment: I think your own solution is much less confusing, then any of the answers given so far :)

Comment: You should not be using `reduce` as it's a partial function: `scala> Vector[Int]().reduce(_ + _)
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.reduceLeft`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tail recursive function will work even if the Vectors have different lengths and can be applied to any numeric type:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def recSum[T : Numeric](s : Iterable[Iterable[T]]) : List[T] = {
  val goodVecs = s.filterNot(_.isEmpty)

  if(goodVecs.isEmpty) 
    List.empty[T]
  else 
    goodVecs.map(_.head).sum :: recSum(goodVecs.map(_.tail))
}
```

Applying it to your example:

```
recSum(Seq(Vector(1.0,2.0), Vector(3.0,4.0,5.0))) //List(4.0,6.0,5.0)

recSum(Seq.empty[Vector[Double]]) // List()
```

Comment: `scala> Seq[Int]().head
java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list`

Comment: @KevinMeredith I don't understand your comment.  What was the input value that caused this exception?

Comment: My mistake for not elaborating. `Seq#head` should not be used, was my point. Please see http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/03-rec-poly.html#total-and-partial-functions.

Comment: @KevinMeredith In general I agree that head is unsafe.  However, in this case I am assured that every `Vector` in my `goodVecs` Seq has at least 1 element because of the `filterNot`.  Therefore, the `NoSuchElementException` can never be thrown.  If I were applying head to the input sequence then your argument, and accompanying article, would be completely correct.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you took in your original question is along the same lines I would do it. Since you raised a concern about efficiency, my answer includes the use of iterators, so that operations like `zip` and `map` will simply return a new iterator, rather than rebuilding an entire collection. I also adapted your approach to work for any non-zero number of input vectors.

Example input:

```
val vecs = Seq(   
  Vector(1,2,3,4,5),
  Vector(2,3,4,5,6),
  Vector(8,2,6,4,2),
  Vector(2,8,4,8,8) 
)
```

First step, transform the Seq[Vector] to a Seq[Iterator]

```
val iterators: Seq[Iterator[Int]] = vecs.map(_.iterator)
```

Now `reduce` that `Seq` into a single iterator. This is pretty similar to what you wrote in your original question:

```
val sumIterator = iterators.reduce[Iterator[Int]]{ (itrA, itrB) =>
  // combine 2 of the iterators into a sum of their individual parts
  // the resulting iterator will then be combined with the next iterator
  // so you end up with a single iterator of the total sum for each 'column'

  (itrA zip itrB) map { case (a, b) => a + b }
}
```

You can now use the `sumIterator` to find the sums of each 'column' in your 'matrix'.

```
sumIterator.toList
// List(13, 15, 17, 21, 21)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the inner `Vector`s with `sum`, then reduce the outer `Seq` with `sum`:

```
scala> val vectors: Seq[Vector[Double]] = List(Vector(.1,.2),Vector(.3,.4))
vectors: Seq[Vector[Double]] = List(Vector(0.1, 0.2), Vector(0.3, 0.4))

scala> vectors.map(_.sum).sum
res10 Double = 1.0
```